# Is there a function to sum x and y where y is the number after x in a pandas series? .shift() in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, data-science

Given a DataFrame:

```
   Number
0    4
1    6
2    2
3   -1
```

Is there an easy and clean way to sum the first number(4) with the number after(6) and the sum(6) with(2) and so on. And is it possible to return a `Pandas.series` and add it as a new column of the dataframe with NaN where the number does not have a number after?.

For example, for the given Dataframe:

```
   Number Sum
0    4     10
1    6     8
2    2     1
3   -1     NaN
```

where 10=4+6, 8=6+2, and 1=2-1

**SOLUTION**

`.shift()` function helped me to solve this problem!
Code:

```
df['Sum'] = df['Number'] + df['Number'].shift(-1)
```

and the output is:

```
   Number Sum
0    4     10
1    6     8
2    2     1
3   -1     NaN
```

Comment: The Pandas `shift` function: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html should help you here

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like commented, `shift()` should be useful in this case:

```
df['Sum'] = df['Number'] + df['Number'].shift(-1)
```

Output:

```
   Number   Sum
0       4  10.0
1       6   8.0
2       2   1.0
3      -1   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate it